# Received message addressed to a similar email address, which is not mine

Tags: gmail

I sometimes receive emails that are not sent to my Gmail address but to very similar Gmail address. The only difference is dot between name and surname.
I'm not talking about spam, they are real mails sent by real persons to another real person, that has the same name as I do.

When I try to send email to that other account, emails are returning to me.

Is it possible, in any kind of circumstances, that gmail server can mistakenly think that these two emails are the same?